# Python socket connect() vs. connect_ex()

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I would like to take a look at those 2 functions in Python. I did some research and bumped into something like this:

> socket.connect_ex(address)
>
> Like connect(address), but return an error indicator instead of raising an exception for errors returned by the C-level connect() call (other problems, such as “host not found,” can still raise exceptions). The error indicator is 0 if the operation succeeded, otherwise the value of the errno variable. This is useful to support, for example, asynchronous connects.

I totally get this. I wrote a simple port scanner to test efficiency and got interesting results:

```
[*] start scanning on host 127.0.0.1 for ports range(0, 65535) with 
method(connect)
[*] method connect finished in 0:00:12.253352
[*] start scanning on host 127.0.0.1 for ports range(0, 65535) with 
method(connect_ex)
[*] method connect_ex finished in 0:00:06.839319
```

So, `connect_ex` seems to be twice as efficient as `connect`. If it comes to syntax the only difference is that with `connect` you surround it by `try except` and catch an error when it fails to connect and with `connect_ex` you check the result for being 0 or errno. That is all clear but my question is why `connect_ex` works faster than `connect`? What reason is down there causing such behaviour?

Comment: You've answered your question, it's the try-except block. Scanning 65535 ports should raise about 65500 exceptions!

Comment: Ok so it's caused straight by creating many exception objects instead of integers as I understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

**socket.connect(address)** ->
Connect to a remote socket at address. (The format of address depends on the address family — see above.)

If the connection is interrupted by a signal, the method waits until the connection completes, or raise a socket.timeout on timeout, if the signal handler doesn’t raise an exception and the socket is blocking or has a timeout. For non-blocking sockets, the method raises an InterruptedError exception if the connection is interrupted by a signal (or the exception raised by the signal handler).

Raises an auditing event socket.connect with arguments self, address.

Changed in version 3.5: The method now waits until the connection completes instead of raising an InterruptedError exception if the connection is interrupted by a signal, the signal handler doesn’t raise an exception and the socket is blocking or has a timeout (see the PEP 475 for the rationale).

**socket.connect_ex(address)** ->
Like connect(address), but return an error indicator instead of raising an exception for errors returned by the C-level connect() call (other problems, such as “host not found,” can still raise exceptions). The error indicator is 0 if the operation succeeded, otherwise the value of the errno variable. This is useful to support, for example, asynchronous connects.

Raises an auditing event socket.connect with arguments self, address.

Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html